# bash grep results into array

Tags: arrays, bash, grep

In bash I'm trying to collect my grep results in array, each cell holding each line.
I'm downloaing urls with this line

> wget -O index -E $CurrentURL

and then i want to grep the 'index' file results (other urls) into array each line per cell,
what should be the correct syntax?

> Array=(`grep "some expression" index`)

??

Comment: This is where you need to find the links, correct? so where will links be? It is tough to create a comprehensive Regex for URLs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 readarray GREPPED < <(grep "some expression" index)
 for item in "${GREPPED[@]}"
 do
     # echo
     echo "${item}"   
 done
```

Oh, and combine those `-v` greps like so:

```
 egrep -v '\.(jpg|gif|xml|zip|asp|php|pdf|rar|cgi|html?)'
```

Comment: thanks, i'll improve my code with that, the first block of code you wrote me doing what? reading from such array or the first line also puts to array?

Comment: The first line outputs to array: http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html; The other 4 lines just demo how to (whitespace-safely) iterate over them

Comment: Note that 'readarray' is a very new addition to Bash.  It is available on nearly none of the Linux servers, or even Cygwin and Mingw installations where I work. If you want a portable solution, see my 'Probably most...' post below.

Answer (score 4):

Probably most elegant among several poor alternatives would be to use a temp file.

```
wget $blah | grep 'whatever' > $TMPFILE
declare -a arr
declare -i i=0
while read; do
    arr[$i]="$REPLY"
    ((i = i + 1))
done < $TMPFILE
```

I don't have time to explain why, but do not pipe directly into read.

No Unix shell is an appropriate tool for this task.  Perl, Groovy, Java, Python... lots of languages could handle this elegantly, but none of the Unix shells.