# Bash value in array

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following

```
#!/bin/bash
aprograms=`pgrep a`
echo $aprograms
```

which outputs:

```
alejandro@ubuntu:~$ bash test.sh 
2 6 7 8 12 13 16 17 20 27 ...
```

I want to control if there is a value inside $aprograms.
I tryed the following (Which I dont know if its even a valid approach):

```
if [ $value in $aprograms ];then
    echo "found"
```

But doesnt work. Is there a correct way to control if there is a value is inside $aprograms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use bash's [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

```
shopt -s extglob
var="2 6 7 8 12 13 16 17 20 27"
if [ "${var/17?( )/}" != "$var" ] ; then echo "match"; fi
```

Comment: That would also detect `17` in a string `1177`

Comment: Then it would not detect `17` if it happens to be the last or the first value in that string. :) But I like the direction in which your answer is going.

Comment: Good find! Edited answer. You should be in QA.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo () {
  echo 2 6 7 8 12 13 16 17 20 27
}

function search_value () { 
  for i in $2; do {
    if [ $i -eq $1 ]; then {
      echo "found"
    } fi
  } done
}

search_value 13 "$( foo )"
```

Just change `foo` with your input program:

```
search_value 13 "$( pgrep a )"
```

Comment: It's worth remembering that this solution works only for string containing integer values. `search_value a "a b c"` will throw an error.

Comment: That's true, reading question example I've guessed he is working with integers. Some `"` around variables and using `==` as operator instead of `-eq` should work even for strings.

Comment: Yeah. Also I was a little shocked that apparently bash is immune to __semicolon injection__ when I tried to serve it something like `search_value 12 "1 ; do; end ; ls ;"` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ " $aprograms " =~ \ $value\  ]] ; then
    echo "found"
fi
```

Also, with `grep`

```
if pgrep a | grep -q -w "$value" ; then
    echo "found:
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-eq
```

is equal to

```
if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ]
```

Comment: But the question was about finding an element in something what looks like an array, not about comparing values.

Comment: see if this will helping , [bash grep results into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205777/bash-grep-results-into-array)

Comment: the solution will a combination of all of this

Answer (score 0):

Since `pgrep` outputs PIDs one per line, you can use `grep` to find the one you're looking for.

```
#!/bin/bash
aprograms=$(pgrep a)
echo "$aprograms"
if grep -Fxqs "$value" <<< "$aprograms"
then
    echo "found"
fi
```

Always quote variables when they are expanded in order to preserve whitespace.

The `-F` option to `grep` uses the pattern as a fixed string instead of a regex. The `-x` option matches the whole line so smaller strings or numbers don't match parts of larger ones. The options `-q` and `-s` suppress output and error output. If your version of `grep` doesn't have these, then use:

```
if grep -Fx "$value" <<< "$aprograms" > /dev/null >&2
```