# Why bash cant find my variable from compgen into a loop?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to push some variables into a bash array. For some reasons I cant understand, my script find the variable `templates_age` directly but not in the loop.

You can try the code on [BASH Shell Online](http://goo.gl/cuhWTj).

script:

```
templates_age="42"
templates_name="foo"
echo "age=${templates_age}"
echo "name=${templates_name}"

readarray GREPPED < <($(compgen -A variable | grep "templates_"))
for item in "${GREPPED[@]}"
do
    echo "${item}"
done
```

output:

```
age=42
name=foo
./main.sh: line 32: templates_age: command not found
```

I tried different kind of `echo "${item}"` without success.

To convert from `grep` to array, I am using this [logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8205856/1248177).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly populate array from a command's output use **process substitution** without `$(...)` which is called *command substitution*:

```
readarray -t grepped < <(compgen -A variable | grep "templates_")
```

Also note use of `-t` to trim newlines.

**Full script:**

```
templates_age="42"
templates_name="foo"
echo "age=${templates_age}"
echo "name=${templates_name}"

readarray -t grepped < <(compgen -A variable | grep "templates_")
declare -p grepped

for item in "${grepped[@]}"
do
    printf "%s=%s\n" "${item}" "${!item}"
done
```

Comment: Ok it is better like this. No error is printed. With your line I got the name of the variable, but not the value of the variable. How can I get it?

Comment: Perfect! Works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you want to use `compgen` and `grep` here. Wouldn't this be enough?

```
for item in "${!templates_@}"; do
    printf '%s=%s\n' "$item" "${!item}"
done
```

If you really want to populate an array, it's as simple as:

```
grepped=( "${!templates_@}" )
```

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the reference manual.

Comment: This is far better indeed. Since @anubhava fixed explicitly my problem, I will let him the resolve flag. If someone has my problem again, try this solution!